# I need to show a PDF icon for when there is a matching file in a directory

Tags: php

I would like to show a PDF icon that links to a file in a directory, for where the name of the file matches a specific pattern.

I have attempted this with the PHP script below, but I do not see the PDF icon, please advise me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance

### PHP Script

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$result = $dbh->query("
    SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
      a_aif.fee_source_id,
      a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
      a_aif.document_filing_date,
      IF (a_aif_remaining.aif_id IS NULL, 0, 1) `match`
    FROM  a_aif
      LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining
        ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
    ORDER BY aif_id DESC");

$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$url = "http://www.theauditorsreport.com/_documents/fees/aifs/".$row[fee_source_id];
$imgsrc = "./images/pdf.gif";

?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th><b>Document ID</b></th>
    <th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Filing Date</b></th>
    <th><b>PDF</b></th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $index => $row) : ?>
<tr data-recordId="<?=$row[fee_source_id];?>"
    class="<?=$row["match"] ? "match" : "";?>">
    <td><?php echo $row[fee_source_id]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[company_name_per_sedar]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row[document_filing_date]; ?></td>
    <td><a href=<?php echo $url ?><img src=<?php echo $imgsrc ?></a></td>
</tr>
<? endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Comment: Please please *please* quote your array keys and HTML element attributes, eg `$row['fee_source_id']` and `<img src="<?php echo $imgsrc ?>">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Just try with the following :***

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$result = $dbh->query("
    SELECT a_aif.aif_id,
      a_aif.fee_source_id,
      a_aif.company_name_per_sedar,
      a_aif.document_filing_date,
      IF (a_aif_remaining.aif_id IS NULL, 0, 1) `match`
    FROM  a_aif
      LEFT JOIN a_aif_remaining
        ON a_aif_remaining.aif_id = a_aif.aif_id
    ORDER BY aif_id DESC");

$result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$imgsrc = "./images/pdf.gif";

?>

<table>
<tr>
    <th><b>Document ID</b></th>
    <th><b>Pubco Name</b></th>
    <th><b>Filing Date</b></th>
    <th><b>PDF</b></th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($result as $index => $row) : ?>
<tr data-recordId="<?php echo $row['fee_source_id'];?>" class="<?php echo $row['match'] ? "match" : "";?>">
    <td><?php echo $row['fee_source_id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['company_name_per_sedar']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['document_filing_date']; ?></td>
   <?php 
$filename = '/_documents/fees/aifs/'.$row['fee_source_id'].'.pdf';
if (file_exists($filename)) {?>
    <td><a href="http://www.theauditorsreport.com/_documents/fees/aifs/<?php echo $row['fee_source_id'].".pdf"; ?>" target="_blank" title="pdf<?php echo $row['fee_source_id']; ?>"><img border="0" title="pdf<?php echo $row['fee_source_id']; ?>" src="<?php echo $imgsrc; ?>" alt="pdf<?php echo $row['fee_source_id']; ?>" /></a></td>
<?php } else {?>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<?php }?>
</tr>
<? endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a great solution and works. However, I need to add ".pdf" to the end of the url. Do you know how I could do that? Never mind, solved that. Just put .pdf outside the PHP in that line. Thanks for your help! Now I just need to find a way to make the PDF Icon show up ONLY IF there is a PDF in that directory that matches this file.

Comment: i have added .pdf in answer check it now

Comment: any idea how I can make the PDF show up only if there is a file?

Comment: that's for empty space also that Abbreviation is : "Non-Breaking Space"

Comment: hmm it doesn't seem to be showing any PDFs now, even where I would expect there to be one

Comment: check it in your folder if the file was uploaded ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22297/discussion-between-john-peter-and-ben-jones)

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an HTML error with this line:

```
<td><a href=<?php echo $url ?><img src=<?php echo $imgsrc ?></a></td>
```

Whereas, it is missing a few corrections (mainly quotes and ending of the `<a>` tag, as well as the `<img>` tag):

```
<td><a href="<?php echo $url ?>"><img src="<?php echo $imgsrc ?>"></a></td>
```

Hopefully, this can point you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks Samuel. You were the first to point this out and your solution works too. Do you have any idea how I can have the PDF Icon show up ONLY when there is a match? thanks